# How can upgrade google api v2 into v3?

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

How can upgrade google api v2 into v3? I would like to upgrade my source code in to v3.
I tried searching google, but I didn't get any suitable results.

```
var maprecent;
function init_maprecent() {
    function createMarker(point, myHtml) { 
        var marker = new GMarker(point);
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() 
        { maprecent.openInfoWindowHtml(point, myHtml, {maxWidth:200}); }); return marker; }
        var markerindex = 0; var markers = new Array();
        function animate_marker() {
            if(markerindex==markers.length) {markerindex=0;} 
            GEvent.trigger(markers[markerindex], "click"); markerindex++; 
            setTimeout(animate_marker, 5000);
        }

        var bottomLeft = new GControlPosition(G_ANCHOR_BOTTOM_LEFT);

        maprecent = new GMap2(document.getElementById("smallmaprecent"));     
        maprecent.addControl(new GSmallZoomControl());     
        maprecent.addControl(new GMapTypeControl(), bottomLeft);

        maprecent.setCenter(new GLatLng(11.25,-60.66667), 10);

        var m0 = createMarker(new GLatLng(-32.3153071,115.8290544),
        'Project on abcd.com<br>Oct 04 2010 03:41PM<br><a target="_parent" href="http://www.gurusocialscript.com/project_9_project-on-freelancerclonescriptcom.html">View project</a><br>2  ');
        maprecent.addOverlay(m0);
        markers.push(m0);
        maprecent.addOverlay(new GPolygon([new GLatLng(-32.3153071,115.8290544), 
    new GLatLng(-32.3153071,115.8290544), 
    new GLatLng(-32.3153071,115.8290544),
    new GLatLng(-32.3153071,115.8290544), 
    new GLatLng(-32.3153071,115.8290544)],
     "#000000", 1, 0.5, "#444488", 0.1));</br></br></br>
    animate_marker();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to go through the documentation for version 3, and rewrite any version 2 code to use its version 3 counterparts.

For example, `new GMap2()` would become `new google.maps.Map()`, `new GLatLng()` would become `new google.maps.LatLng()` and so on.

Comment: Like I say, you'll need to go through your the API documentation and your code. There's no real, sure-fire, programmatic way to "upgrade" your code from version 2 to version 3; you're going to have to do it yourself.